# Mysql calculate with the max() value

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit stuck cause am not sure if I am looking the wrong way casue I can't find anything related to what I am looking for. So I want to give an example for what I am trying to do. NOTE: not real scenario.

I have a count on a field:

```
SELECT count(user_id) 
FROM usersgroups 
group by user_id
```

Now I want to make a calc with the max value from the count. Something like:

```
SELECT count(user_id) as count,  
       SUM(max(count(user_id)) / count(user_id)) as blub 
FROM usergroups 
group by user_id
```

But I get error invalid use of group function cause I think I cant use the COUNT() function inside the SUM function?

So is there any other way to make that calculation.

P.S. the calc is for calculating the percentage of the max value to the record/current value.

UPDATE

So what I expect is a percentage like

```
 count | percentage 
5      | 1
4      | 0.8
3      | 0.6
2      | 0.3
1      | 0.2
```

- 5/5 = 1
- 4/5 = 0.8
- 3/5 = 0.6
- 2/5 = 0.4
- 1/5 = 0.2

Comment: "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please read the link which Raymond has shared. Some **minimal and relevant** sample data and expected output will be helpful for generating quick response from the community :)

Comment: I have added an example output. If that is not enough i will create a example db

Comment: in my SQL that I wrote: SELECT count(user_id) as count. So its an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a separate [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can fetch the maximum count value out of all the counts. I have simply used `ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC LIMIT 1` to fetch the same.
- `CROSS JOIN` this result-set with the `usergroups` table, so that every row in the `usergroups` table has access to the maximum count value.
- Now, you can simply use the `GROUP BY` and appropriate aggregation to determine the "percent".
- Note that, for `GROUP BY` to be valid, `SELECT` clause must contain either aggregated columns/expressions only, or the columns specified in the `GROUP BY` clause. That is why `MAX()` is used over the maximum count value. Since that value is only a scalar, so `MAX()` will return the same value only.

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  ug.user_id, 
  COUNT(ug.user_id) AS user_count, 
  COUNT(ug.user_id) / MAX(mcnt.count) AS percent
FROM 
  usergroups AS ug 
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS count
  FROM usersgroups 
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC LIMIT 1
) AS mcnt
GROUP BY ug.user_id 
ORDER BY user_count DESC
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Am gonna dissect this code and try to add it in my real scenario. Thats a query thats alot larger and alot more going on. But this will help me alot I think. So again thank you!

Comment: @NielsLucas happy to help. Feel free to ask any questions later with your larger query; on how to accomodate this into there. I have added explanation; it should be handy.

Comment: @NielsLucas now I look back at my answer; I had unnecessarily complicated it. Please check at the revised (and optimized) solution now.

Comment: your new version always returns 1.000 percent. Typo?

Comment: @NielsLucas rollbacked to original solution. I overthinked and tried to optimize but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Count available user_id as subquery, then divide user_id values by the sum of count.

```
 select  user_id/ sum(count) as percentage 
    from(
        select count(user_id) as count , user_id
        from usergroups
        where user_id != 0
        group by user_id
    ) as A
    group by count, user_id
```

Comment: First of all i get an error cause mysql doesn't like the [count], so i removed the []. And the percentage is always 0.0001. So that is not accurate.

Comment: it does work, but I get percentage like 10241.0000. Thats not correct... max percentage should be 1 and others should be between 0.0 - 0.9